# MySQL compare results 0 and 1

Tags: mysql, select, compare

I need to get a result from two selects, and compare them.

Their values should return **0 *or* 1**, if one of them is 1, then it's 1.
1 will always have a greater priority than 0.

This:

1. 1st returns **0**, 2nd returns **1**, then it's **1**.
2. 1st returns **1**, 2nd returns **0**, then it's **1**.
3. Both returns **1**, obviously it's **1**.
4. Both returning **0**, finally it's **0**.

Comment: post your initial query, could the query return more than 1, how is that handled?

Comment: no, it will always be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in another SELECT and use OR. MySQL already treats 1 as true and 0 as false.

Try these:

```
SELECT (SELECT 1) OR (SELECT 0) AS result
// Returns 1

SELECT (SELECT 0) OR (SELECT 0) AS result
// Returns 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the two expressions in [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to return the greatest value, which would be `1` if either is `1` and `0` if neither is:

```
SELECT GREATEST(col1, col2) AS result
```

If it is across two subselects:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
  (SELECT col1 FROM tbl1 WHERE val='something'),
  (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE val='something else')
) AS result
```